# Reload/Restart ASP.NET Core 2.1 web application

Tags: c#, datacontext, asp.net-core-2.1

I have a .NET Core 2.1 web app where users can select the database provider of their choice. It's a choice between SQL Server, SQLite and MySQL (for now, more providers could be added later). I am saving user's choices to a json file along with the connection strings for each database provider:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "MSSQL": "Server=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=ABC_db;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true",
    "SQLite": "Data Source=ABC.db"
  },
  "UserSettings": {
    "DatabaseProvider": "MSSQL", //this changes as per user's selection
    "GenerateDb": false //this will be false for the first time, after that it will be true
  }
```

And in my `ConfigureServices` method in `Startup.cs` I have placed some checks to register/inject the database context and identity:

```
GenerateDb = Configuration.GetValue<bool>("GenerateDb");
            DatabaseProvider = Configuration.GetValue<string>("SystemSettings:SystemProfile:DatabaseProvider");
            if(GenerateDb)
            {


                if (DatabaseProvider == "MSSQL")
                    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => 
                    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString(DatabaseProvider)));

                else if (DatabaseProvider == "SQLite")
                    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>   options.UseSqlite(Configuration.GetConnectionString(DatabaseProvider)));

                services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
                    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
            }
```

and this code works as expected, it sets the database context with whatever provider the user has selected. The only problem is that to *activate* the database context, I have to stop and start the app again so next when it reads the json file, `GenerateDb` is true. I am looking for something that can help me restart the app without manually doing it. Is this functionality available? I couldn't find anything in the docs.

Comment: Do you realize that will change it for all users who hit your site?

Comment: Yes, this database change will only occur once, so that is not an issue.

Comment: So each user has his or her own database, completely separated from the databases of all the other users?

Comment: No, there is only one database, this "database selection" happens only via the admin panel and it will happen before the website is ready to be used(no visitors before this selection). Once admin selects the database provider (among other things), the website is ready to be used and `DatabaseProvider` in the json file will be forever set to whatever the admin selected and `GenerateDb` will be set to true.

Comment: So you want to set up a website with a configurable database type.... But why not wait starting the web site until it has been configured, i.e. until the database type has been selected? That is the way one would normally deal with this type of problem.

Comment: Yes, that is what I'm doing right now. I select the database and other option and stop the debugging in VS, then launch it again to "restart" the app. Just wondering if there a way to do it via code.

Comment: I think you should consider configuring the website (i.e. choosing db provider) and running the web site to be two completely different operations - both while developing (debugging) and in production. This will make life easier for you, I think. But I may misunderstand you and for sure I don't know what your requirements are :).

Answer (score 0):

An option would be to register 2 different implementations of `ApplicationDbContext`.

First, create the new classes (they can be empty implementations, it doesn't matter)

```cs
public class SQliteApplicationDbContext : ApplicationDbContext {}
public class SqlServerApplicationDbContext : ApplicationDbContext {}
```

Then register them as such:

```cs
services.AddDbContext<SqlServerApplicationDbContext >(options => 
    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString(DatabaseProvider)));

services.AddDbContext<SQliteApplicationDbContext>(options =>   
    options.UseSqlite(Configuration.GetConnectionString(DatabaseProvider)));

services.AddScoped<ApplicationDbContext>((ctx) =>
{
    // fyi: would be better to implement the options pattern here
    DatabaseProvider = Configuration.GetValue<string>("SystemSettings:SystemProfile:DatabaseProvider");
    if (DatabaseProvider == "MSSQL")
        ctx.GetService<SqlServerApplicationDbContext >();
    else if (DatabaseProvider == "SQLite")
        ctx.GetService<SQliteApplicationDbContext>();
    else
        throw new Exception("Bad configuration");
});
```

Note that this makes the assumptions that asp.net core is configured to watch the changes in the `json` file.

Comment: Thank you for the response, will this *reload/restart* the entire application if any change is detected in the json file?

Comment: No, only the configuration file, but since the resolution of the context is determined at runtime, it's not an issue (for this anyway)

Comment: Can I inject/use Identity the same way? Because injecting identity requires `ApplicationDbContext` class in `services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()`

Comment: Identity would work out of the box (it doesn't actually create a an instance of `DbContext` as far as I can tell)